# signature changes

Tags: java, string, arrays

can anyone suggest me how to convert byte array to string? This method does not work:

```
byte [] my_array=....;
String my_string = new String (my_array);
```

or

```
String my_string = my_array.toString();
```

What I want to do is to convert signature to string and pass it to so other side. But when I use method above and method then my_string.getBytes() signature changes and then fails to verify.

I mean for example my_string changes when I do `my_string.getBytes().toString()` 
or my_array changes after `(new String(my_array)).getBytes()`

Thanks.

Comment: You need to specify the encoding when converting from byte array to String. The constructor `String(byte [] bytes)` uses the system's default charset. There is a constructor taking the array and the charset.

Comment: You need to clarify what kind of data is your input (byte[], but containing what), what kind of "conversion" do you want to do and what do you want to do with it (what does "pass to the other side" mean). Why can't you just pass the byte[]?

Answer (score 4):

(You haven't stated so explicitly, but I'm assuming your byte array is a cryptographic signature of some kind.)

You're doing two things wrong here:

- Trying to create a string from an arbitrary byte array directly: your byte array does *not* represent encoded text, so don't treat it that way.
- Even if it *did*, you'd be using the platform default encoding, which is almost always a bad idea.

The most common way of handling arbitrary binary data as text in a reversible form is to use [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). There's a public domain base64 Java library [here](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) (and plenty of other free options too):

```
byte[] signature = ...;
String signatureBase64 = Base64.encode(signature);

// Propagate signatureBase64 to the other side, then...

byte[] signature = Base64.decode(signatureBase64);
```

Comment: yes, I use that, for example: Base64.encodeBase64(signature); returns byte array. I use import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; What library should I use to work with such method like Base64.encode(signature);    thank you

Comment: @innspiron: The one I added a link to in my answer... it's got a better API than the Apache Commons Codec one, IMO.

Comment: In order to return string using apache commons codec library you need to use Base64.encodeBase64String(byte[] input) // returns string

Answer (score 1):

Both `new String()` and `getBytes()` implicitly use the platform default encoding and are overloaded to allow you to specify the encoding (which should almost always be done). Apparently your platform default encoding cannot represent all the byte values in your array.

But wanting to convert bytes to String and back is almost always the wrong thing to do in the first place. What exactly does this "signature" contain, and what is this "other side" you think you have to convert it to String for?

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode byte array into [Base64.](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html) You may also use methods - `printBase64Binary()` and `parseBase64Binary()` of javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter to encode or decode Base64.